# Pyspark column: convert string to datetype

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to convert a pyspark column of string type to date type as below.

```
**Date**
31 Mar 2020
2  Apr 2020
29 Jan 2019
8  Sep 2109
```

Output required:

```
31-03-2020
02-04-2020
29-01-2019
08-04-2109
```

Thanks.

Comment: Basically, I want to extract, Year, month and date as separate columns. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dayofmonth,year,month` (or) `date_format()` (or) `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())` in built functions for this case.

**`Example:`**

```
#sample data
df=spark.createDataFrame([("31 Mar 2020",),("2 Apr 2020",),("29 Jan 2019",)],["Date"])
#DataFrame[Date: string]
df.show()
#+-----------+
#|       Date|
#+-----------+
#|31 Mar 2020|
#| 2 Apr 2020|
#|29 Jan 2019|
#+-----------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("new_dt", to_date(col("Date"),"dd MMM yyyy")).\
withColumn("year",year(col("new_dt"))).\
withColumn("month",month(col("new_dt"))).\
withColumn("day",dayofmonth(col("new_dt"))).\
show()

#+-----------+----------+----+-----+---+
#|       Date|    new_dt|year|month|day|
#+-----------+----------+----+-----+---+
#|31 Mar 2020|2020-03-31|2020|    3| 31|
#| 2 Apr 2020|2020-04-02|2020|    4|  2|
#|29 Jan 2019|2019-01-29|2019|    1| 29|
#+-----------+----------+----+-----+---+

#using date_format
df.withColumn("new_dt", to_date(col("Date"),"dd MMM yyyy")).\
withColumn("year",date_format(col("new_dt"),"yyyy")).\
withColumn("month",date_format(col("new_dt"),"MM")).\
withColumn("day",date_format(col("new_dt"),"dd")).show()

#+-----------+----------+----+-----+---+
#|       Date|    new_dt|year|month|day|
#+-----------+----------+----+-----+---+
#|31 Mar 2020|2020-03-31|2020|   03| 31|
#| 2 Apr 2020|2020-04-02|2020|   04| 02|
#|29 Jan 2019|2019-01-29|2019|   01| 29|
#+-----------+----------+----+-----+---+
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your first option. I get the error as "
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Comment: @Lilly, Could you add your dataframe schema?

Comment: "Date" column is string type. Thanks.

Comment: @Lilly, I added creating dataframe step and date is `string` type, Code works fine with string type too!

Comment: @Shu , can we convert date format back to %B%y format? example resultant as 'Jan-21'

Answer (score 1):

The **`to_date`** function would need days as **`02`** or **`' 2'`** instead of **`2`**. Therefore, we can use **`regex`** to remove spaces, then wherever the **`length`** of the string is **`less than`** the **`max(9)`**, we can add **`0 to the start`** of the string. Then we can apply **`to_date`** and use it to extract your other columns(day,month,year). Can also use **`date_format`** to keep your date in a *specified format*.

```
df.show()#sample df
+-----------+
|       Date|
+-----------+
|31 Mar 2020|
|2  Apr 2020|
|29 Jan 2019|
|8  Sep 2019|
+-----------+

from pyspark.sql import functions as F    
df.withColumn("regex", F.regexp_replace("Date","\ ",""))\
  .withColumn("Date", F.when(F.length("regex")<9, F.concat(F.lit(0),F.col("regex")))\
              .otherwise(F.col("regex"))).drop("regex")\
  .withColumn("Date", F.to_date("Date",'ddMMMyyyy'))\
  .withColumn("Year", F.year("Date"))\
  .withColumn("Month",F.month("Date"))\
  .withColumn("Day", F.dayofmonth("Date"))\
  .withColumn("Date_Format2", F.date_format("Date", 'dd-MM-yyyy'))\
  .show()

#output
+----------+----+-----+---+------------+
|      Date|Year|Month|Day|Date_Format2|
+----------+----+-----+---+------------+
|2020-03-31|2020|    3| 31|  31-03-2020|
|2020-04-02|2020|    4|  2|  02-04-2020|
|2019-01-29|2019|    1| 29|  29-01-2019|
|2019-09-08|2019|    9|  8|  08-09-2019|
+----------+----+-----+---+------------+
```